# "Compact" insert in file with php

Tags: php

I want insert the big result of query in txt file.

when the file have 600Mb of row, I obtain an error and a file is not open with Notepad because is very big.

There is a method for insert data in txt file, that efficiently and saves space?

I insert with this row:

```
fwrite($fp, $FileResult."\r\n");
```

Thanks

EDIT:
the output of query is like:

```
(
 'a',
)
(
 'b',
)
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to     allocate
 133955641 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\prove\provaBackground1.php on line 94
```

Comment: Cool story, bro. Got a question?

Comment: Are you trying to append additional data to the end of an already big file? or just save a big load of data?

Comment: I obtain the result of query and insert this result in txt with a foreach cicle.

Comment: Can you filter your result set, or at least put a limit 0,2000  2000,2000, 4000, 2000 etc etc...

Comment: maybe I can filter, but if I could INSERT everything would be better

Comment: _"I obtain an error"_. Is this where the guessing game about what the error is, starts?

Comment: I insert the error

Comment: Well that sure cleared things up

Comment: I do not know if there is a way to enter compact data in a file. because with a txt file of 600Mb , Notepad or Microsoft Word can not read it

Comment: And assuming there is a Magical Hex-Portion that would help compact the 600MB Data so you could save it as a 6 MB .txt File, did you consider the fact that it may not still be readable by your Notepad? Perhaps you may need to catch up on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php